# VBA Code to Empty a text file without deleting it

Tags: excel, vba

I need to empty a text file without deleting it.  I have read/write privileges on the file, but I don't have create file privileges in the folder.  I've tried:

Open "C:\Folder\MyFile.txt" for Output as #1

but that command appears to cause the existing copy of MyFile.txt to be deleted and then recreated empty.  I'm only guessing because it says I don't have permission to run that command.

Any ideas on how I can keep MyFile.txt from being deleted but setting it back to empty so I can refill it with new data?

Comment: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/how-can-i-clear-the-contents-of-a-text-file/

Comment: Thanks for the link.  That worked.  But in the end the Open … for Output … also worked.  The mistake that I had made is giving privileges to the wrong account to read/write the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a early binding VBA solution

```
Sub DeleteFileContent()

    Dim fileSysObj As New FileSystemObject
    Dim txtStream As TextStream

    Const fileName = "...\Documents\Delete My content.txt"
    If fileSysObj.FileExists(fileName) Then
        Set txtStream = fileSysObj.OpenTextFile(fileName, ForWriting, True, TristateUseDefault)
        Call txtStream.Write("")
        Call txtStream.Close
        Set txtStream = Nothing
    End If

End Sub
```